# Purescript Halogen Handling SVG

Tags: purescript, halogen

Is there an accessible way to utilize svg elements in purescript halogen? I'm trying to draw a dynamic, clickable, graph within an `<svg>`, but the only reference I can find to `svg` is in Halogen.Themes.Bootstrap, which seems to be more concerned with css themeing.

Comment: Trying to work this out myself. They're not included, but it should be possible to create any XML element - poke around in src/HTML/Elements.purs for how it's done for the included ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Halogen doesn't provide a module for SVG elements, but you can construct your own elements in the appropriate namespace. If you're using the currently tagged release version (v0.12.0), then these you can use the `Element` constructor from `Halogen.HTML.Core`: https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-halogen/0.12.0/docs/Halogen.HTML.Core#t:HTML